# How to see the query that defines a view in SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am sure this is a simple question, but I am having no luck getting it answered.

I have a number of views in a MS SQL 2008 database I am now supporting but I am not able to find how to access the queries that define the views. I need to see that to get a list of all tables and databases the views are accessing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

several ways, right click on the view and select SCRIPT View AS-->CREATE TO--> New Query Window (see picture below) , don't click design because the designer doesn't support CASE and other statements

or

```
sp_helptext 'ViewName'
```

or

```
select object_definition(object_id('ViewName'))
```

or

```
select name, object_definition(object_id) 
from sys.views
where name = 'ViewName'
```

'

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling I was missing rights and was not setup correctly. I was unable to see run these due to restrictions, and this helped me figure out what rights I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on your view in the Object Explorer and select *Design*. If you do not see the SQL, then click the SQL button (likely 3rd button from the left) on the toolbar.

You can also right-click and select *Script View as/Create To/New Query Editor Window*.